# rust lifetime problem, why the first call not compile error?

Tags: rust

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NumRef<'a>(&'a i32);

impl<'a> NumRef<'a> {
    // my struct is generic over 'a so that means I need to annotate
    // my self parameters with 'a too, right? (answer: no, not right)
    fn some_method(&'a mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut num_ref = NumRef(&5);
    num_ref.some_method(); // mutably borrows num_ref for the rest of its lifetime
    num_ref.some_method(); // compile error
    println!("{:?}", num_ref); // also compile error
}
```

'a is should be 'static, num_ref's lifetime is shorter then 'static

Comment: hi @bilosikia, what do you mean with `answer: no, not right`? If it is not right, why do you still paste it with the lifetime annotation?

Comment: i think the first call should compile error, but the fact is not

Comment: There is no reason for the first call to be a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've told Rust that `some_method` needs `self` for `'a`.

But by definition `'a` lives for longer than the instance of NumRef.

This means the only way to fulfill your requirement is to create a borrow which lasts for the entire lifetime of the instance, aka as soon as the method is called you're completely locked out.

You can just remove the lifetime bound from the `self` entirely:

```rust
impl<'a> NumRef<'a> {
    fn some_method(&mut self) {}
}
```

These lifetimes are essentially unrelated: here `some_method` cares about `NumRef`, not `'a`.

Comment: 'a lives for longer the instance, but why not compilation failure?

Comment: Because there's no reason for a compilation error to occur?